# What is the oxidation state of copper and iron in chalcopyrite?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, oxidation-state, minerals

What is the oxidation state of Cu and Fe in chalcopyrite ($\ce{CuFeS2}$)?
Some websites tell that it is $\ce{Cu(I)Fe(III)S2}$, and others tell that it is $\ce{Cu(II)Fe(II)S2}$. Which is right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A number of papers report that the formal valency states of chalcopyrite are best considered as $\ce{Cu+Fe^3+S2}$, based on various computational and spectroscopic evidence.

**References:**

1. Klekovkina, V. V.; Gainov, R. R.; Vagizov, F. G.; Dooglav, A. V.; Golovanevskiy, V. A.; Pen’kov, I. N. Oxidation and magnetic states of chalcopyrite CuFeS2: A first principles calculation. *Opt. Spectrosc.* **2014,** *116* (6), 885–888. [DOI: 10.1134/S0030400X14060149](https://doi.org/10.1134/S0030400X14060149).
2. Pearce, C.; Pattrick, R.; Vaughan, D.; Henderson, C.; van der laan, G. Copper oxidation state in chalcopyrite: Mixed Cu d9 and d10 characteristics. *Geochim. Cosmochim. Acta* **2006,** *70* (18), 4635–4642. [DOI: 10.1016/j.gca.2006.05.017](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.gca.2006.05.017).
3. Goh, S. W.; Buckley, A. N.; Lamb, R. N.; Rosenberg, R. A.; Moran, D. The oxidation states of copper and iron in mineral sulfides, and the oxides formed on initial exposure of chalcopyrite and bornite to air. *Geochim. Cosmochim. Acta* **2006,** *70* (9), 2210–2228. [DOI: 10.1016/j.gca.2006.02.007](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.gca.2006.02.007).

Answer (score 1):

One clue to the likely oxidation state is offered by some experiments I was doing in the chemistry laboratory when I was in graduate school.  Looking for a clue to how thiourea might alter copper ekectrodeposition, I tried adding this stuff in bulk to copper(II) salt solutions.

- Copper sulfate gave a loss of color, blue -> colorless.
- Copper chloride gave a white precipitate and then it dissolved, forming a colorless solution, when more thiourea was added.

Given that white or colorless copper compounds are typically copper(I), it appeared that thiourea reduces and complexes the copper, and **in the sulfur-ligand environment provided by thiourea copper favors the +1 oxidation state.**

A Cu(I)-Fe(III) model for chalcopyrite, where the metals are bonded to sulfur, would be quite consistent with such findings.